# How to copy an html form fields value to another field on click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Friends how can i do the following? I am having three input fields

```
 <input name="firstname" type="text" class="text" id="firstname" value="" />
 <input name="lastname" type="text" class="text" id="lastname" value="" />
 <input name="displayname" type="text" class="text" id="displayname" value="" />
```

I want to do this. After the user enters the first name and lastnaeme and then he clicks on the display name field, it should be populated with a value as "firstname lastname", How can I do it javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add onclick or keypress events on the displayname element with function -

```
function populateDisplayName(){
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstname');
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastname');
    document.getElementById('displayname').value = firstName.value + ' ' + lastName.value;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CmVpB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var fullName = document.getElementById('displayname');
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
fullName.value = firstName.value + ' ' + lastName.value;
```

Comment: need to put the above code in a function and attached that function to onclick event of displayname input text box.